# CSS a property for specific id pseudo class?

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Any one know how to apply a css propert to the a tag, but only when it's in a certain div?  I would like the .router_li div to have the hover effect, but any other links.  I'm not sure what this is called.

I think it's called a pseudo class, and I'm not doing it right.
I tried this:

```
a:router_li:hover{
  background-color:yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2c5fac;
  border: 1px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs, classes and pseudo-classes are different things, and CSS has different notations for all three:

- [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors)
- [Class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html)
- [Pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes)

If you want to apply this particular `:hover` (which is a pseudo-class) only when `a` is a `div` with class `router_li` (as in `<div class="router_li">`), use

```
.router_li a:hover
```

That's a class, though; if it's an ID (as in `<div id="router_li">`), use

```
#router_li a:hover
```

In both cases, `router_li` is not a pseudo-class since it is defined in the markup and not in CSS, so the `:router_li` in your code is invalid. Also notice that the ID/class (whichever it is) comes before the `a:hover` - this is called a contextual selector (`a` only when it's in a certain `div`).

Answer (score 2):

Use the parent `id` as part of the selector:

```
#parentId a {
    /* specific CSS styles */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j3aAd/).

This isn't a `pseudo-class`, of course (that encompasses such things as `:hover`, `:checked`, `:focus`), or a `pseudo-element` (which would be `::before` and `::after`). This is simple inheritance, selecting an element based on an ancestor, and is what the space implies between the `#parentId` and the `a`.

You could, instead, use the `>` immediate child combinator if there were no other ancestors/descendants between the `div` and the `a`.

References:

- [CSS selectors, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

Answer (score 0):

`.router_li a:hover` will only target hovered anchor tags within a `.router_li` element